# How to parsing image from XML page in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsxmlparser

Hi I am developing one news iOS  application ,I am getting Tittle and Description from XML but i am not able to get Image from XML can any one help me out of this please .

**Note:** I am new for this iOS Development please help me how to solve this issue . Thanks in Advance .

Here is my code .

**In NewsViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NewsViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,NSXMLParserDelegate>
@property (strong,nonatomic)IBOutlet UITableView *tblNews;
@property (strong,nonatomic)IBOutlet NSMutableArray *arrTitles;
@property (strong,nonatomic)IBOutlet NSMutableArray *arrDescription;
@property (strong,nonatomic)IBOutlet NSMutableArray *arrImages;
@property (strong,nonatomic)IBOutlet NSMutableArray *arrDate;

@end
```

**In NewsViewController.m**

```
#import "NewsViewController.h"
#import "NewsTableViewCell.h"
#import "NewDetailsViewController.h"

@interface NewsViewController ()
{
    NSString *temString;
    NSMutableString *strTemp;
}

@end

@implementation NewsViewController
@synthesize arrImages;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - View Life Cycle
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.arrTitles =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.arrDescription=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.arrImages=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.arrDate=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self makeRequestForNews];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma  mark - make request for news
-(void)makeRequestForNews//http://www.shura.bh/MediaCenter/News/ExportNewsAsXml.aspx?Section=%D8%A3%D8%AE%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%AC%D9%84%D8%B3
{
    NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.shura.bh/MediaCenter/News/ExportNewsAsXml.aspx?Section=%D8%A3%D8%AE%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%AC%D9%84%D8%B3&RetrieveImageUrl=true"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    //After making request the apparent thing is expecting the response that may be expected response or an Error. so create those objects and intialize them with NULL.
    NSURLResponse *response = NULL;
    NSError *requestError =NULL;
    //Once you have response with you , Capture YOur Responce data using NsData.

    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&requestError];

    //Convert the respnse Data into Response String.

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //Now We can start parsing the Data using XMl parser . you need XML parser in-order to use the below class method "dictionaryFOrXMLString".

    NSError *parserError = NULL;

    //XML parsing

    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:responseData];
    [xmlParser setDelegate:self];
    [xmlParser parse];

  //NSDictionary *xmlDict = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:responseString error:NULL];

    //once you have xmlDict handy, you can pass this to the any ViewController (Like table view) to populate the Data.

}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[arrImages objectAtIndex:0]];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"ShuraNews"])
    {

    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"PUBLISHINGPAGEIMAGE"])
    {

        NSLog(@"dict === %@",attributeDict);
    }
    strTemp=[NSMutableString new];
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    //temString =string;
    [strTemp appendString:string];
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"TITLE"])
    {
        NSLog(@"temstring=== %@", strTemp);
        [self.arrTitles addObject:strTemp];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"PUBLISHINGPAGECONTENT"])
    {
        NSLog(@"temstring=== %@", strTemp);
        [self.arrDescription addObject:strTemp];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"NEWSARTICLEDATE"])
    {
        NSLog(@"temstring=== %@", strTemp);
        [self.arrDate addObject:strTemp];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"PUBLISHINGPAGEIMAGE"])
    {
        NSURL *PUBLISHINGPAGEIMAGE = [NSURL URLWithString:@"strImage"];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:PUBLISHINGPAGEIMAGE];
        UIImage *arrImages = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
        NSLog(@"temstring=== %@", strTemp);
        [self.arrImages addObject:strTemp];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"ShuraNews"])
    {

        [self.tblNews reloadData];
    }
}
#pragma mark - TabeView Datasource//delegate method

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.arrTitles count];

}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"cellNews";
    NewsTableViewCell *cell=(NewsTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[NewsTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        // cell.NewsTableViewCell.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x000000);
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    }
    if( [indexPath row] % 2){
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor =UIColorFromRGB(0Xffffff);

    }
    else{
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor =UIColorFromRGB (0Xdcdcdc);
    }

    //selectbackgroun color start
    UIView *NewsTableViewCell = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
    NewsTableViewCell.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0Xdcdcdc);
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = NewsTableViewCell; //select background colro end
    cell.lblTitles.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GEEast-ExtraBold" size:12];
    cell.lblTitles.text=[self.arrTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblDescription.font =[UIFont fontWithName:@"GE SS Unique" size:12];
    cell.lblDate.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"GE SS Unique" size:12];
    cell.lblDescription.text=[self.arrDescription objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblDate.text=[self.arrDate objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblTitles.textAlignment= NSTextAlignmentRight;
    cell.lblDate.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    cell.lblDescription.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
   // cell.imgNews.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"homeh"];
  //  cell.imgNews.image=[self.arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImage *arrImages = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:arrImages];
    return cell;
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *dict=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
        [self.arrTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]],@"title",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
        [self.arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]],@"img",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
        [self.arrDescription objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]],@"Des", nil];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NewsDetailsID" sender:dict];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"NewsDetailsID"])
    {
        ((NewDetailsViewController *)segue.destinationViewController).strTitle=[sender objectForKey:@"title"];
        ((NewDetailsViewController *)segue.destinationViewController).strDescription=[sender objectForKey:@"Des"];
    }
}

@end
```

**My XML Format is :**

```
<ShuraNews>
    <QueryProperties>...</QueryProperties>
    <Articles TotalItems="256" TotalRowsExactToReturnItems="False">
    <Article ItemNo="1">
    <URL>
    http://www.shura.bh/MediaCenter/News/CouncilNews/Pages/14-05-14(2).aspx
    </URL>
    <TITLE>
    فيما أشاد رئيس "الشؤون الخارجية" في البرلمان الايرلندي بالتطور الاقتصادي بالمملكة .. الجشي: علاقاتنا مع ايرلندا ايجابية..ونأمل بالمزيد من التعاون البرلماني والتجاري بين البلدين
    </TITLE>
    <AUTHOR></AUTHOR>
    <RANK>1000</RANK>
    <DESCRIPTION/>
    <WRITE>15/05/2014 01:05:55 ص</WRITE>
    <ISDOCUMENT>1</ISDOCUMENT>
    <SIZE>83798</SIZE>
    <SITENAME>http://www.shura.bh/mediacenter/news/councilnews</SITENAME>
    <CREATED/>
    <NEWSARTICLEDATE>13/05/2014 05:00:00 م</NEWSARTICLEDATE>
    <CONVENIENTPERIOD>الرابع</CONVENIENTPERIOD>
    <TERM>الثالث</TERM>
    <PUBLISHINGPAGEIMAGE>
    <img alt="" border=1 src="/MediaCenter/News/Committees/HRC/PublishingImages/DSC_5804.JPG" width=450 style="border:1px solid">
    </PUBLISHINGPAGEIMAGE>
    <PUBLISHINGPAGECONTENT>
    القضيبية – مجلس الشورى اكدت سعادة الدكتورة بهية جواد الجشي النائب الثاني لرئيس مجلس الشورى رئيسة لجنة الصداقة البحرينية الايرلندية بالمجلس على أن مملكة البحرين تولي اهتماما كبيرا لإقامة علاقات تعاون مع مختلف دول العالم في إطار من الاحترام المتبادل والمصالح المشتركة، مشيرة إلى أن العلاقات مع جمهورية إيرلندا تحظى بالتقدير والاعتزاز، معربة في الوقت ذاته عن أملها في أن تنعكس تلك العلاقات الإيجابية على رفع مستوى التعاون البرلماني والتجاري بين البلدين، منوهة بالدور المحوري للجان الصداقة البرلمانية على صعيد تقريب وجهات النظر وتبادل الآراء حول مختلف الموضوعات محل الاهتمام المشترك. واعربت الجشي عن ترحيبها بالزيارة التي يقوم بها سعادة السيد بات برين رئيس لجنة الشؤون الخارجية والتجارة في البرلمان الإيرلندي الى مملكة البحرين،  والتي من شأنها البناء على علاقات الصداقة المتميزة والوثيقة القائمة بين البلدين، والارتقاء بها نحو مجالات أرحب من التعاون بما يخدم  البلدين والشعبين الصديقين، حيث تضمنت الزيارة لقاء معالي رئيس مجلس النواب، ووزير التجارة والصناعة وبالمملكة، إلى جانب زيارة شركة الخليج لصناعة البتروكيماويات ومنطقة البحرين العالمية للاستثمار. من جانبه، أشار رئيس لجنة الشؤون الخارجية والتجارة في البرلمان الايرلندي إلى ان العلاقات القائمة بين مملكة البحرين وجمهورية ايرلندا هي علاقات ايجابية ومتنامية في مختلف المجالات، مشيدا بالتطورات الاقتصادية الجارية في مملكة البحرين، فيما اكد على اهمية الزيارة الاخيرة التي قام بها وفد لجنة الصداقة البحرينية الايرلندية بمجلس الشورى إلى جمهورية ايرلندا، وما اسهمت به الدعوة التي تلقاها من رئيسة الوفد سعادة الدكتورة بهية الجشي لزيارة المملكة في فتح القنوات لتطوير العلاقات القائمة بين مملكة البحرين وجمهورية ايرلندا.
    </PUBLISHINGPAGECONTENT>
    <COMMENTS>
    اكدت سعادة الدكتورة بهية جواد الجشي النائب الثاني لرئيس مجلس الشورى رئيسة لجنة الصداقة البحرينية الايرلندية بالمجلس على أن مملكة البحرين تولي اهتماما كبيرا لإقامة علاقات تعاون مع مختلف دول العالم في إطار من الاحترام المتبادل والمصالح المشتركة
    </COMMENTS>
    <ARTICLEBYLINE/>
    <PUBLISHINGROLLUPIMAGE>
    <img alt="" border=1 src="/MediaCenter/News/Committees/HRC/PublishingImages/DSC_5804.JPG" style="border:1px solid">
    </PUBLISHINGROLLUPIMAGE>
    </Article>
    </ShuraNews>
```

Comment: Unrelated to the original question, but I would discourage you from doing synchronous network requests (whether the original XML or the images). Your UI will be choppy if you do this. For example, you should use `sendAsynchronousRequest`.

Comment: Also, you probably don't want to be loading the images into an array, but rather just save the image URLs in the array, and then have `cellForRowAtIndexPath` retrieve the image (ideally asynchronously) from the server. I don't know how many rows you might conceivably have, but if you had hundreds/thousands, you would encounter memory problems. By letting `cellForRowAtIndexPath` retrieve the image, you'll only be instantiating `UIImage` instances for the visible cells, which is far more memory-efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, there are a number of issues:

1. The XML is, technically, not well-formed. Your XML contains:

   ```
   <PUBLISHINGPAGEIMAGE>
   <img alt="" border=1 src="/MediaCenter/News/Committees/HRC/PublishingImages/DSC_5804.JPG" width=450 style="border:1px solid">
   </PUBLISHINGPAGEIMAGE>
   ```

   If this is truly what your XML looks like, it's not well-formed. This URL should be contained in a `CDATA` (i.e. start with `<![CDATA[` and end with `]]>`) or the `<`, `>`, and `&` should be replaced with `&lt;`, `&gt;` and `&amp;`, respectively. Which means that it should have looked like:

   ```
   <PUBLISHINGPAGEIMAGE>
   &lt;img alt="" border=1 src="/MediaCenter/News/Committees/HRC/PublishingImages/DSC_5804.JPG" width=450 style="border:1px solid"&gt;
   </PUBLISHINGPAGEIMAGE>
   ```

   or

   ```
   <PUBLISHINGPAGEIMAGE>
   <![CDATA[<img alt="" border=1 src="/MediaCenter/News/Committees/HRC/PublishingImages/DSC_5804.JPG" width=450 style="border:1px solid">]]>
   </PUBLISHINGPAGEIMAGE>
   ```

   So, if you fix that, you can then successfully retrieve a value for `PUBLISHINGPAGEIMAGE`.
2. Having done that, you now need to extract the URL from this HTML. To do this properly, you probably should use a HTML parser, like HPPLE, but for something as simple as this, you can also use regular expression:

   ```
   - (NSString *)findFirstImgUrlInString:(NSString *)string
   {
       NSError *error = NULL;
       NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(<img\\s[\\s\\S]*?src\\s*?=\\s*?['\"](.*?)['\"][\\s\\S]*?>)+?"
                                                                              options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                                error:&error];

       NSTextCheckingResult *result = [regex firstMatchInString:string
                                                        options:0
                                                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

       if (result)
           return [string substringWithRange:[result rangeAtIndex:2]];

       return nil;
   }
   ```
3. Having done that, you can extract the `src` for the `img` HTML tag. Note, that is a relative URL:

   ```
   /MediaCenter/News/Committees/HRC/PublishingImages/DSC_5804.JPG
   ```

   You'll obviously have to identify the base URL is and then append this URL to it. It would appear that you have to grab the element named `URL` from the XML, extract the base URL from that, and then append the above image URL to that.

Comment: @Khasim By the way, you could theoretically ignore the fact that the XML is malformed, and just parse the `img` tag as if it was XML instead of HTML. (I wouldn't advise that approach ... it's always better to fix the data source, if you can, rather than coding around a malformed XML.) Anyway, if you wanted to parse the `img` as if it was XML, you can then get the `src` from the `attributeDict` in `didStartElementName` method.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your Valuable suggestions . Can you please tell me how to parse the image with didStartElementName method . I just recently started to learn the Xcode so please edit my code and show me how we can display the image so that i can easily understand it. Thanks in Advance .

Comment: @Khasim Just look for `img` element name, and if true, then grab `attributeDict[@"src"]` to get the relative image path.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your Reply. As you said i tried like this but its not coming. please check my code -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
   
    
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"ShuraNews"])
    {
        
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"PUBLISHINGPAGEIMAGE"])
    {
       
   NSLog(@"src: %@",[attributeDict objectForKey:@"src"]);
    }
    strTemp=[NSMutableString new];
}

Comment: @Khasim If you have not fixed your XML, then you'd do `if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"img"]) { NSLog(@"src: %@",attributeDict[@"src"]); }`. The problem is that the malformed XML will make the `img` HTML tag look like an XML element (when we both know it really isn't). So, if you don't fix the HTML, treat `img` as if it were an XML tag. Also note, you have two `img` tags, so make sure you grab the right one. But you should really fix the XML and follow the answer outlined in my answer above.

Comment: Okay fine , ill do that and update you the result . Thanks .khasim

Comment: Hi , Actually  i am unable to fix the XML , i tried with if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"img"]) { NSLog(@"src: %@",attributeDict[@"src"]); } .. but i am not getting it .. can you please edit my above code and show me how we can do it . please